# List of values does not fit line

Tags: line-breaking

Have a look at the code below. The list of values for `\alpha` and `\beta` are too long to fit one line and the last values of each list disapears. Therefore I want them to break as soon as the edge of the page is reached. Ideally, the value that starts on on the new line, starts right below the value of the line above. How can this be done?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

$\alpha = (190476.9;  265284.6;  262604.6; 1051346.9;  228362.3;  230331.0; 238756.5 ; 469647.5;  390560.8;  344014.0)$\\

$\beta = (1.0000000; 2.4906065; 2.6086442; 8.4893781; 1.4392259; 0.9334028; 0.7777668; 0.9556785; 1.4311763; 0.3567257)$\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are prepared to break these by hand or do you want something automatic?  Also are these inline expressions or is OK to make them displays?

Answer (score 2):

Breaking lines are easily done in the text mode. So if it doesn't matter splitting the code into math and text part, this can be used.

```
\noindent$\alpha = {}$(190476.9;  265284.6;  262604.6; 1051346.9;  228362.3;  230331.0; 238756.5 ; 469647.5;  390560.8;  344014.0)

\noindent$\beta = {}$(1.0000000; 2.4906065; 2.6086442; 8.4893781; 1.4392259; 0.9334028; 0.7777668; 0.9556785; 1.4311763; 0.3567257)
```

Answer (score 2):

By default `;` is of class `\mathpunct` which does not allow line breaks, you can make it "math active" whith a definition that allows breaks and allows quite flexible space. Note you should never end a paragraph with `\\` so I deleted those from the example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\semicolon}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3B}
{\catcode`\;\active
\gdef;{\semicolon\linebreak[0]\mskip7mu plus 5mu minus 3mu\relax}}
\mathcode`\;="8000

\begin{document}
\errorcontextlines10
$\alpha = (190476.9;  265284.6;  262604.6; 1051346.9;
228362.3;  230331.0; 238756.5 ; 469647.5;  390560.8;  344014.0)$

$\beta = (1.0000000; 2.4906065; 2.6086442; 8.4893781;
1.4392259; 0.9334028; 0.7777668; 0.9556785; 1.4311763; 0.3567257)$
\end{document}
```